# Cannot run ant build.xml

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I have a project build using ANT. When I try to run the buld.xml it shows the following error.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\user3\workspace\cube_web\build.xml:64: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\jdk1.7"
```

What should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error message itself contains the solution

> Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.

1. You need to check that in the environment variables you have JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK bin directory.
2. Try to compile and run a simple java program and see if it works.

In case you are using windows

- right click the My Computer icon.
- Choose Properties from the context menu.Click the Advanced tab.
- Click Environment Variables. Find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
- Make sure it points to **bin** directory in jdk.

Comment: Do i need to add JAVA_HOME to `C:\jdk1.7\bin` ?

Comment: the path depends on your system and where you have installed jdk

Comment: try running a simple java program

Comment: Read this http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html. Probably your apache ant installation is broken.